# Column Calculated #Name? error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I am creating a new column type in a SharePoint 2013 Online Document Library in order to parse a file name.

Currently I have this formula I can add into `=MID([Title],1,FIND(".",[Title],1)-1)`

This parses my folder John.Smith and gives me John. Although for my Adobe PDF it gives me `#Name?`

Do you know how to make it parse the PDF and Excel file as well?

Thanks

[image]

This is the picture of what I was saying.
[image]

Comment: It should work if you edit the pdf metadata and add a Title to the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Name column cannot be referenced in a calculated column. You can see proof of this by looking through the list of Columns available when creating or editing your calculated column formula.

If you want to work around the issue, create a second column and then use a workflow to copy the Name column to the new column you created. The new column can be referenced in your calculated column.

The easiest way to create the workflow would be in [SharePoint Designer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491). Set the workflow to start anytime an item is created or changed and the one step would be to set your new column to the value of the Name column.

Creating the workflow is very easy. Once you have downloaded and installed SharePoint Designer, connect to your site and create a new Workflow (a 2010 workflow is sufficient for this purpose). Set up the workflow as follows. The first image shows the workflow settings and the second image shows the single step you'll need to create. In the second image, `NameCopy` is the name of the column I am copying the Name column into.

[image]

Comment: If you look at his formula, he isn't using the Name field at all

Comment: Name & Title are oddly the same.

Comment: Is there a Lag in Sharepoint before it works?

Comment: Set NameCopy to [%Current Item:Name%]...... Why does it have %?